# Huge Tree Hierarchy for navigation

Tags: ux-designer, tree

I've a tree structure which extends to 6 levels down. 
When I get inside as a user I like to show the tree structure in my left panel and content on the right.

But I'm worried since too much of data in the right panel makes the user soo busy.

how can I optimise this? And also I should have an option to navigate inside the table of contents.

Comment: Can you provide some screens or examples of what you have got so far?

Comment: I can't share in public, can I please have your mail ID?

Comment: You can just make a similar style mockup with dud names and data, it doesn't have to look great or like the real deal but just so we can get a better idea of what you're talking about.

Comment: No I would not give out my email information onto a public forum. I get enough junk mail.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this level of complexity can be supported in various ways, e.g.:

1. **Shortcuts** – you can suggest most popular places somewhere in the interface.
2. **Search** – let your users find what they look for, support the tree with a quick, on the fly search field using mechanisms as *fuzzy search* (e.g. searching for 'folder construction' should also find '**construction** of **folder**s', *error correction* (e.g. searching for 'floder' should find 'folder') and *synonyms* (e.g. searching for 'directory' should find 'folder' as well).
3. **Interlinking** – in big structures like this one, exact categorisation may be problematic. Users may be looking for 'red shoes' in either 'red' or 'shoes' branch for example. Hence telling them that there is another place where the content they might be looking for would live, may be important.
4. **Use analytics** & **user feedback** to analyse where they make mistakes and provide improvements within the tree structure (still: be careful about it and provide a navigation from old branch to new branch to let users know how its placement has changed).